# what does "serialization provides a method for detecting changes in time varying data." mean?

Tags: serialization, bigtable

I have read many articles regarding the serialization and its ability to update fetched/stored data in time-varying!

Actually, I don't understand how does this happen?

Could anyone please give me a **short explanation** about this sentence:

```
serialization provides a method for detecting changes in time varying data
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're quoting from the [Wikipedia page on Serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization):

> ### Uses
>
> - [...]
> - A method for detecting changes in time-varying data.

The answer is in the paragraph at the end of that section:

> Since both serializing and deserializing can be driven from common code (for example, the Serialize function in Microsoft Foundation Classes), it is possible for the common code to do both at the same time, and thus, 1) detect differences between the objects being serialized and their prior copies, and 2) provide the input for the next such detection. It is not necessary to actually build the prior copy because differences can be detected on the fly. The technique is called differential execution. It is useful in the programming of user interfaces whose contents are time-varying — graphical objects can be created, removed, altered, or made to handle input events without necessarily having to write separate code to do those things.

In other words, if you serialize an object O at time T0 and keep a copy of it, then in the future, at time T1, you can deserialize the object from the backup copy at T0 and compare it to the live-running object at T1, or, alternatively, serialize the same object O at the new time T1 and compare the two serialized versions for differences.